# Recovering filenames from a folder in linux using python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the listdir function from the os module in python to recover a list of filenames from a particular folder.
here's the code:

```
import os
def rename_file():
    # extract filenames from a folder
    #for each filename, rename filename
    list_of_files = os.listdir("/home/admin-pc/Downloads/prank/prank")
    print (list_of_files)
```

I am getting the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

it seems to give no trouble in windows, where you start your directory structure from the c drive.

how do i modify the code to work in linux?

Comment: does prank/prank exist ?

Comment: On the computer that you want to run this code, open up the command line and use the `cd` command to navigate into the directory that you want to work with. Then use `pwd` to get the full path to that folder. Then copy-paste that path into your script, and you'll stop getting that error

Comment: please triple check your directory name - it simply does not exist.

Comment: You could check existence of the file/directory with: `os.path.exists()`

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct. There should be some error with the path you provided. 
You could open a terminal and enter into the folder first. In the terminal, just key in `pwd`, then you could get the correct path. 
Hope that works.

Comment: you could get current path with python `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function to exclude that error with check of existence of file/directory:

```
import os
def rename_file():
    # extract filenames from a folder
    #for each filename, rename filename

    path_to_file = "/home/admin-pc/Downloads/prank/prank"
    if os.exists(path_to_file):
        list_of_files = os.listdir(path_to_file)
        print (list_of_files)
```

Comment: why not `list_of_files = os.listdir(path_to_file)` ?